# PHP logout cookies and sessions

Tags: php, cookies

I have a simple website on localhost at the moment. I am working on security. I created an additional column in the database and named it "active_notactive" of type enum('0', '1').

**My question: How to change the active_notactive feild to 0 on the logout of that specific user.**

What I want to achieve is: Before the user logs in, active_notactive='0' , after they login active_notactive='1' , when they logout='0'. I got all of them to work apart from the logout bit.

Here is my logout script:

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();



// HERE IS WHERE IM STUCK
// get session email to use it in the following query
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
// Update member to active
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET active_notactive='0' WHERE email=$email");




// delete the current dession
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();

// set the current cookie to 1 hour ago (to delete it)
setcookie ("online_security_user", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("online_security_pass", "", time() - 3600);

?>

<h2>Thank you for using our website. You are now logged out.</h2>
```

Comment: **NEVER** assume a query succeeds. If you had even basic error handling in place, e.g. `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` you'd have seen why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET active_notactive='0' WHERE email='".$email."'");
```

$email needs to be in quotes as it is string.

and also above answer `$email= $_SESSION["email"]` needed.

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS ! I LOVE U LOL

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work?

And I think you mean `$email = $_SESSION['email'];`.

Comment: it doesnt change it to '0' in the database on logout :(

Comment: Then start debugging. Print the query before executing it, enable error reporting, look if you get errors.